# Views contextual filter on just ONE of the listed contenttypes

Tags: views

I'm not sure how I can accomplish this but I hope you can tell me.
I have a view that lists 2 different contenttypes that has different filters.

Now, I want to use a contextual filter on just one of the contenttypes.

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on your specific view configuration. Generally speaking, you can add validation (e.g. what content type to accept as contextual filter) and a fallback behavior (e.g. ignore argument vs. show 404), see screenshot. With these instruments you can achieve pretty much.

[image]

Comment: I tried this but I can't get it to work. My "regular" filters look like filter group 1: published AND type = trip. OR filter group 2: type = business. Then I do the settings for the contextual nid filter, enter the nodeID and the business nodes dissapear from the results.

Comment: I have updated the screenshot. Which contextual filter do you use? I think you need the `Content: nid` filter and then specify the required content type in the validation, see the screenshot. Otherwhise, could you give us more information about your setup, like where and how should the view be displayed?

Comment: I'm attaching a screenshot to this comment. Stops and PHP is excluded from output and PHP is empty (used it for testing earlier). The content type filter is set to show Trip and Business. I've set up the contextual filter `Content: nid` like you did in your screenshot except for the "does not validate", it's set to show all results but it still just show the results from current node id.
http://i.imgur.com/dwm9LdV.jpg